# Extra spaces in <pre> tag

Tags: html, css

I have this issue with my pre tag that I have been trying to resolve for a while now. I have tried almost 20 suggestions that I have found and none of them seem to work.

I have a server running with node.js that has 2 websites on it, technically it's one website with 2 layouts. If I try using pre-tag on my 1st layout, everything seems to be displaying normally, however on my 2nd page I guess extra tabs that I can't seem to locate.

Here is what I have:

```
<pre>&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code &gt;
&lt;script&gt;
    new Chart(document.getElementById(&quot;bar-chart&quot;), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [&quot;Blue&quot;, &quot;Black&quot;, &quot;Green&quot;, &quot;Silver&quot;, &quot;Red&quot;],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: &quot;Votes for this color: &quot;,
                    backgroundColor: [&quot;#3e95cd&quot;, &quot;#000000&quot;, &quot;#35d90e&quot;, &quot;#c0c0c0&quot;, &quot;#c45850&quot;],
                    data: [120, 384, 81, 223, 192]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Best Car Colors according to a 1000 votes survey'
            }
        }
    });
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</pre>
```

and it is displaying like this:
[Visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw9Q0.jpg)

anyone have any idea what and why? I have tried unsetting all css and re-setting pre tag, but it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: We need to see the issue itself to be able to help. Please provide a link to a fiddle or codepen as monners suggested, or a link to your website where it is happening.

Comment: https://my-app-ddemin.herokuapp.com/crashcourse -> References ->Bar Chart (and you will see js/html tabs)

Comment: On your page, the spaces are there in the source. So if you type `&lt;script&gt;` and you end up with `​​​  ​​​ ​​​ ​​​ ​​​ ​​​ ​​​ ​​​ ​​​  ​​​ &lt;script&gt;` in the result, something happens during upload. Not a problem with the CSS of your pre element.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, what does this mean? During upload? How can i diagnose/fix this? I have only been doing this for 3-4 month, so I might be off a bit

Answer (score 2):

Updated:

For all those who were and are still struggling with same issue, I found the problem! So I am using handlebars, and one the features is called "partials"

and I had a page that called on those partials, in this manner:

```
{{>crashcorse/intro_lessons}}
```

however it had some extra spaced before the {{> }} tag, due to auto formatting, removing these extra spaced seem to solved the issue.